# The date not transformed correctly

Tags: php, jquery

```
<?php
$file = fopen("admin/events/events.txt", "r");
while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
$result=htmlentities($line);
$s = $result;
preg_match_all('/data-day=\'([^\']*)\'/', $s, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $idx => $datevalue)
{
    $year = substr($datevalue, 0, 4);
    $month = substr($datevalue, 4, 2);
    $day = substr($datevalue, 6, 2);
}
$line = str_replace("<div data-role='day' data-day='$year$month$day", "<b><u>Datum:</b></u> $year-$month-$day ", $line);
$line = str_replace("'><div data-role='event' data-name='<h1>", " <br><b><u>Event:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-start='", " <br><b><u>Start:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-end='", " <br><b><u>Einde:</b></u> Tot ", $line);
$line = str_replace("' data-location='", " <br><b><u>Locatie:</b></u> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("</h1>", " <br><b><u>Inhoud event:</b></u><br> ", $line);
$line = str_replace("'></div></div>", "", $line);
echo "<div class='event'>$line</div>"; 
}
fclose($file);

?>
```

I use this code to read out a txt file. The events are then displayed. Now the date in YYYYMMDD format is transformed with the code

```
$result=htmlentities($line);
$s = $result;
preg_match_all('/data-day=\'([^\']*)\'/', $s, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $idx => $datevalue)
{
    $year = substr($datevalue, 0, 4);
    $month = substr($datevalue, 4, 2);
    $day = substr($datevalue, 6, 2);
}
```

to a YYYY-MM-DD format. But there is a problem. For the dates like 21031217 or 20141025,... or whatever. The date is tranformed correct. But there are some dates like 201311 that means 2013 january the first, but that code is tranformed to 2013-11-    So that is not good :). So the months 1-9 and the days 1-9 are single digits what gives problems when the dates are transformed to the other format. Can someone provide me with a oiece of extra code to recognize and transform correct?

maybe the jquery code can be adjusted?

i have a jquery plugin calendar that reads out events on certan dates. Now it gets saved in the format YYYYMMDD, now all works fine for dates like 20131225,20141022 and so on,... The code works also very good with the dates 201411, this is 2014 first of january 2014611 is for example 2014 6th month 11th day. Now i want the dates to be like 20140101 and 20140611 and so on and one. Can someone edit this code. Thx

```
var yy;
var calendarArray =[];
var monthOffset = [6,7,8,9,10,11,0,1,2,3,4,5];
var monthArray = [["JAN","January"],["FEB","February"],["MAR","March"],["APR","April"],["MAY","May"],["JUN","June"],["JUL","July"],["AUG","August"],["SEP","September"],["OCT","October"],["NOV","November"],["DEC","December"]];
var dayArray = ["7","1","2","3","4","5","6"];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.calendar-day.have-events',activateDay);
    $(document).on('click','.specific-day',activatecalendar);
    $(document).on('click','.calendar-month-view-arrow',offsetcalendar);
    $(window).resize(calendarScale);
    calendarSet();
    calendarScale();
});

    function calendarScale() {
        $(".calendar").each(function() {
            if($(this).width() < 400 && !$(this).hasClass('small')) {
                $(this).addClass('small');
            } else if($(this).width() > 400 && $(this).hasClass('small')) {
                $(this).removeClass('small');
            }
        })
    }

    function offsetcalendar() {
        var cm = parseInt($(".calendar").attr('offset'));
        if($(this).data('dir') == "left") {
            calendarSetMonth(cm-1);
        } else if($(this).data('dir') == "right") {
            calendarSetMonth(cm+1);
        }

    }

    function orderBy(deli,array) {
        var p = array.slice();
        var o = p.length;
        var y,t;
        var temparray = [];
        for(var u=0; u<o;u++) {
            for(var uu=0;uu<p.length;uu++) {
                if(uu==0) {
                    t = uu;
                    y = p[uu];
                }
                else if(parseInt(p[uu][deli].replace('.','')) < parseInt(y[deli].replace('.',''))) {
                    y = p[uu];
                    t = uu;
                }
            }
            temparray.push(y);
            p.splice(t,1);
        }
        return temparray;
    }

    function calendarSet() {
        $(".calendar").append('<div class="calendar-month-view"><div class="calendar-month-view-arrow" data-dir="left">â€¹</div><p></p><div class="calendar-month-view-arrow" data-dir="right">â€º</div></div><div class="calendar-holder"><div class="calendar-grid"></div><div class="calendar-specific"><div class="specific-day"><div class="specific-day-info" i="day"></div><div class="specific-day-info" i="month"></div></div><div class="specific-day-scheme"></div></div></div>');
        $(".calendar").each(function() {
            if($(this).data("color") == undefined) {
                $(this).data("color","red");
            }
            $(this).find('[data-role=day]').each(function() {
                var tempdayarray = [];
                $(this).find('[data-role=event]').each(function() {
                    var tempeventarray = [];
                    tempeventarray["name"] = $(this).data("name");
                    tempeventarray["start"] = $(this).data("start");
                    tempeventarray["end"] = $(this).data("end");
                    tempeventarray["location"] = $(this).data("location");
                    tempdayarray.push(tempeventarray);
                });
                calendarArray[$(this).data('day')] = tempdayarray;
            });
        });
        $(".calendar [data-role=day]").remove();
        calendarSetMonth();
    }
    function activateDay() {
        $(this).parents('.calendar').addClass('spec-day');
        var di = new Date(parseInt($(this).attr('time')));
        var strtime = $(this).attr('strtime');
        var d = new Object();
        d.day = di.getDate();
        d.month = di.getMonth();
        d.events = calendarArray[strtime];
        d.tocalendar = tocalendar;
        d.tocalendar();
    }
    var tocalendar = function() {
        $(".specific-day-info[i=day]").html(this.day);
        $(".specific-day-info[i=month]").html(monthArray[this.month][0]);
        if(this.events !== undefined) {
        var ev = orderBy('start',this.events);
        for(var o = 0; o<ev.length;o++) {
            $(".specific-day-scheme").append('<div class="specific-day-scheme-event"><p>'+ev[o]['name']+'</p><p data-role="dur">'+ev[o]['start']+' - '+ev[o]['end']+'</p><p data-role="loc">'+ev[o]['location']+'</p></div>');
        }
        }
    }
    function activatecalendar() {
        $(this).parents('.calendar').removeClass('spec-day');
        $(".specific-day-scheme").html('');
    }
    function calendarSetMonth(offset) {
        $(".calendar-grid").html('');
        var d = new Date();
        var c = new Date();
        var e = new Date();
        if(offset !== undefined) {
            d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+offset);
            e.setMonth(e.getMonth()+offset);
            $(".calendar").attr('offset', offset);
        } else {
            $(".calendar").attr('offset', 0);
        }
        $(".calendar .calendar-month-view p").text(monthArray[d.getMonth()][1]+' '+d.getFullYear());
            d.setDate(1);
            if(dayArray[d.getDay()] == 1) {
                d.setDate(d.getDate()-7);
            } else {
                d.setDate(d.getDate()-dayArray[d.getDay()]+1);
            }
            for(var i=0;i<42;i++) {
                d.setDate(d.getDate()+i);
                var cal_day = $('<div class="calendar-day"><div class="date-holder">'+d.getDate()+'</div></div>');
                if(d.getMonth() !== e.getMonth()) {
                    cal_day.addClass('other-month');
                }
                if(d.getTime() == c.getTime()) {
                    cal_day.addClass('this-day');
                }
                var strtime = d.getFullYear()+''+(d.getMonth()+1)+''+d.getDate();
                if(calendarArray[strtime] !== undefined) {
                    cal_day.addClass('have-events');
                }
                var cal_day_eventholder = $('<div class="event-notif-holder"></div>');
                if(calendarArray[strtime] != undefined) {
                    for(var u=0;u<3 && u<calendarArray[strtime].length;u++) {
                        cal_day_eventholder.append('<div class="event-notif"></div>')
                    }
                }
                cal_day.attr('strtime',strtime);
                cal_day.attr('time',d.getTime());
                cal_day.prepend(cal_day_eventholder);

                $(".calendar-grid").append(cal_day);
                d.setDate(d.getDate()-i);
            }
    }
```

Comment: You would be best doing something like a count on the string and formatting depending on the result.

Comment: i don't think it is an easy task. what would be `2013111`? is it `2013-11-01` or `2013-01-11`?

Comment: idd, but i based a whole jquery plugin on this kind of structure... i know instead of the dates 01 02 an so on :) but thats too late now :p

Comment: edited my question with jquery code

Comment: Can you enforce the format of dates entered into the text file? If not, then this is an impossible task.

Comment: i dont understand this site, why do i get a negative vote, i did research for days to find a solution, and my question is very clear i think. I just provide enough code for the jquery and php masters here... what a bocrap

Comment: An interesting question. I guess that without the suggestion @vascowhite made, it's an impossible task however. The negative vote *might* be the result of this line: `"Can someone edit this code. Thx"`. Most SO users are not so happy with this kind of questions. In fact they are allergic to it.. Just my five cents...

Comment: This is exactly the problem of data in a non-standard way. This will always be ambigious, so you'll simply -have- to change the format of your data if you want to distinguish between several ambigious dates. Any solution to this problem will be just as wrong as translating 201311 to `2013-11-`.

Comment: managed to make it work dispite everyone telling me it couldnt be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By storing your dates in a non-standard form (`YYYYmd`), any solution to this problem will use an arbitrary interpretation of the data. While it -may- go well for certain dates, there will always be dates that are interpretted in a wrong way, and dates that will never logically follow out of any string. You'll simply *have* to change the format to a fixed-width format (`YYYYMMDD`) if you want to solve this problem.

While this might not be the answer you expect on the first part of your question, "Can someone provide me with a [p]iece of extra code to recognize and transform correct?", I believe this to be the only correct answer to the second part of your question.

---

I am not willing to spit through 100+ lines of code to find where you did hide the part where you interpret the date, but if you want every date to make sense (ala it looks like a date), even if said date could be incorrect, you can use a regex to match the date:

```
var a = "201311";
var b = a.match(/^([0-9]{4})([01][012]|[0-9])([1-9][0-9]{0,1})$/);
console.log( b.slice(1).join("-") ); // 2013-1-1
```

It will however be impossible to represent the following dates:

```
Expected "2013-1-11", got "2013-11-1" 
Expected "2013-1-12", got "2013-11-2" 
Expected "2013-1-13", got "2013-11-3" 
Expected "2013-1-14", got "2013-11-4" 
Expected "2013-1-15", got "2013-11-5" 
Expected "2013-1-16", got "2013-11-6" 
Expected "2013-1-17", got "2013-11-7" 
Expected "2013-1-18", got "2013-11-8" 
Expected "2013-1-19", got "2013-11-9" 
Expected "2013-1-21", got "2013-12-1" 
Expected "2013-1-22", got "2013-12-2" 
Expected "2013-1-23", got "2013-12-3" 
Expected "2013-1-24", got "2013-12-4" 
Expected "2013-1-25", got "2013-12-5" 
Expected "2013-1-26", got "2013-12-6" 
Expected "2013-1-27", got "2013-12-7" 
Expected "2013-1-28", got "2013-12-8" 
Expected "2013-1-29", got "2013-12-9"
```

Comment: i see the problem, thx for ur help, i try to rewrite mu plugin

Comment: problem solved, with ur piece of code i managed to adjust my plugin :) so thx